# ArrayList HashMap is undefined

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine, arraylist

Can't seem to figure out why I get this error "`ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[])` is undefined"

```
 // THE ERROR IS RIGHT HERE TO
           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.main,
                    new String[] { TAG_FIRSTNAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.nameFirst, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
           //HERE
```

Here is my code. The idea is to take a JSON from an app engine datastore and then divide it up into a list view.

```
package com.indeeditis; 




public class FinderActivity extends ListActivity   {


private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "nameFirst";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "nameLast";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "emailAddress";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";

private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
JSONArray contacts = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.finder);

   // Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9000);
    //start.setOnClickListener(this);
    new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());

}



public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {

    public Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();

  try {

     // final TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView100);

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

           try{
        //Get the element that holds the earthquakes ( JSONArray )
        JSONArray  contacts = jObject.getJSONArray("item");

        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String nameFirst = c.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
            String nameLast = c.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_FIRSTNAME, nameFirst);
            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);



        }

           }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
           }


             // THE ERROR IS RIGHT HERE TO
           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.main,
                    new String[] { TAG_FIRSTNAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.nameFirst, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
           //HERE
           setListAdapter(adapter);

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error? And please remove the irrelevant code from there. Specially the imports.

Comment: Paste the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: @JBNizet The constructor SimpleAdapter(FinderActivity.EndpointsTask, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined

Comment: First parameter to the SimpleAdapter constructor should be a `Context`.

Comment: Please post your logcat output too....

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis answer works. Thanks all. I'll vote to close in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleAdapter` only has one [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29).

```
public SimpleAdapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
```

You are using

```
new SimpleAdapter(this, // not a Context
                contactList, // List
                R.layout.main, // int
                new String[] { TAG_FIRSTNAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE }, // String[]
                new int[] {R.id.nameFirst, R.id.email, R.id.mobile }); // int[]
```

where `this` is not a `Context`, but a reference to the `EndpointsTask` instance. Use `FinderActivity.this` if `EndpointsTask` is an inner class of `FinderActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

From Android docs ,

```
public SimpleAdapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int 
      resource, String[] from, int[] to)

Added in API level 1

Constructor
Parameters
context     The context where the View associated with this SimpleAdapter 
            is running

data        A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one row 
            in the list. The Maps contain the data for each row, and should 
            include all the entries specified in "from"

resource    Resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for this 
            list item. The layout file should include at least those named views
            defined in "to"

from        A list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with 
            each item.

to          The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. 
            These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are 
            given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.
```

But in your code **this** is not the **`context`** as per specification of constructor.

Use ***`FinderActivity.this`***  . it will work